# Meaning of Path Connectedness

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology

Recently I've been reading through Chapter 9 of Artin's "Algebra". I'm having trouble understanding the proof of a proposition (Proposition 9.7.9, to be precise). It states:

"Let $G$ be a path-connected matrix group, and let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ that contains a non-empty open subset $U$ of $G$. Then $H=G$."

I understand the concepts of connectedness and openness in the real and complex numbers, but here one may depict these notions through illustration. What does it mean, precisely, for a matrix group to be connected? Further, connectedness involves the construction of paths from point to point. What is a "continuous path" in the group of matrices?

I was thinking that maybe it would help to think of an $n$ by $n$ matrix as a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n} $, after which "connected paths in the matrix group" could be "connected paths" in this vector space?

Comment: Yes, as a subset in $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$, the matrix group inherit a topology and thus one can consider continuous path in the matrix group

Comment: Thanks for you answer! Could you specify what kind of topology?

Comment: The Euclidean topology generated by the metric $d(\vec{x},\vec{y})=\sup_{1\le x \le n\times n} |x_i-y_i|$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Let $G$ be a connected matrix group and let $H$ be any subgroup of $G$ containing open nbhd $U$ of $e$. Then $H=G$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3279707/let-g-be-a-connected-matrix-group-and-let-h-be-any-subgroup-of-g-containin)